# ROS Installation on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ros

I am trying to install ROS on Ubuntu but keep running into the following error. Could anyone suggest how to overcome this?

````
==> Building with env: '/home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/src/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/python_orocos_kdl -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/python_orocos_kdl/install'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/src/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/python_orocos_kdl/cmake/FindSIP.py", line 8, in <module>
    import sipconfig
ImportError: No module named sipconfig
CMake Error at cmake/FindSIP.cmake:63 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find SIP
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/python_orocos_kdl/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'python_orocos_kdl': 
  Command '['/home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/src/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/python_orocos_kdl', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/python_orocos_kdl && /home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/src/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/python_orocos_kdl -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/USER/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'```
````

Comment: What version of Ubuntu/ROS (and ROS 1 vs 2) are you using? Assuming you followed the guide ([16.04](https://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)/[18.04](https://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu)), what step were you on? 
Did you deviate from this setup procedure? This is important to debug.

Comment: Looking at the error, it looks like it can't find a python package named sipconfig, which should be installed as a dependency - if this happens again, your installation procedure is missing something. Looking for that package, there are several posts on SO detailing how to deal with that package. If there is a manual build/install component, then your installation is flawed, you shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using Ubuntu version 19.04, which I've read should be ok if I install ROS Melodic Morenia from source. The step I'm on is "Building the catkin Workspace" from http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source. I haven't deviated from the instructions.

Comment: It looks similar to the issue I reported for `rqt`, all packets dependent on SIP are affected: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/211; Basically sip doesn't have `sipconfig` in version 5

Comment: you need sip version 4.19.x, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76349769/19171308

Answer (score 3):

What might be happening is that `sipconfig` is installed, but for a different version of Python (i.e. not Python 2.7). You can fix this by creating a link to `sipconfig.py` in the Python 2.7 `site-packages` directory as follows:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.19.21/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipconfig.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sipconfig.py
```

Note: this was successful on macOS, so the file paths may be different on Ubuntu - particularly the first one (the source file).

---

#### To check whether this is actually the problem:

Try to execute the following import statement in both a Python 2.7 and Python 3 shell. If it fails in both 2.7 and 3, then this is unfortunately not your problem.

```py
import sipconfig
```