# Where is the sipconfig module to make QT5 bindings for PyQT5?

Tags: pyqt5

I'm trying to build PyQt5 bindings for some C++ QT5 code. I've tried following the answer here:

[Is it possible to embed C++ widget to PyQt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258808/is-it-possible-to-embed-c-widget-to-pyqt-application)

The code in the linked repo relies on the sipconfig module, but I haven't been able to figure out where / how to get this module.

Is the sipconfig module still needed? The example code and documentation https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/examples.html
for sip5 doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

`sipconfig` comes inside the [sip](https://pypi.org/project/sip/) package.

If you are using ubuntu's pyqt5 then install it with `apt-get install python3-sip`, otherwise use pip: `python3 -m pip install sip`.

Comment: I did that, but I don't see a sip package in my venv. Only a sipbuild. Is this something I need to compile?

Comment: In Ubuntu 23.04, this does not result in a python pacakage able to be imported called sipconfig

Answer (score 0):

Only `sip` version 4.19.x still provides `sipconfig`, you may need to build version `4.19.x` from source.